# Snapping Horizontal Scrollbar (different item widths)

Tags: android, scrollview, android-scrollview, horizontalscrollview, snapping

I looked through many different posts, but I haven't found any working solution.
There are many solutions for snapping horizontal scrollbars, but every one of them works only, if the items have the same sizes.

I will give you a small example:

The screen is able to show 300px is it's width.
The items inside the scrollbar can have different sizes, like:

- 1: 300px
- 2: 300px
- 3: 500px
- 4: 400px

The whole layout would look like this, if * is 100px:

```
  1    2     3     4
[***][***][*****][****]
```

Now the scrollbar should snap in place exactly at the start/end of an item.
It's easy for the first two items, because they have the same size like the screen. But for the rest I can't think if a working solution.

So if you scroll to the third item, the scrollbar should snap in place right at the beginning of item 3 on the left side of the screen. ( '!' = screen size)

```
  1    2     3     4
[***][***]![***!**][****]
```

If you scroll almost to item 4, the scrollbar should snap in place exactly at the end of item 3 on the right side of the screen.

```
  1    2     3     4
[***][***][**!***]![****]
```

It's so hard to explain. I hope you understand my problem.

Comment: What you mean snapping? Audio effect or clickable scrollbars?

Comment: By snapping I mean, that the item is aligned to the size of the screen. Like swiping through fragments with a viewpager. The fragment snaps in place.